# How many addresses can Bitcoin Core 0.13 **effectively** manage?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, bitcoind, address, address-management

I want to know, what's the maximum amount of addresses that Bitcoin Core 0.13 can manage?
All addresses should belong to the default account.

1. I want to use the `walletnotify` feature
2. How does the startup time depends on the number of addresses my wallet holds?
3. How do other `JSONRPC` calls behave if my wallet holds many addresses?

Comment: I don't have numbers, but my expectation is that the number of addresses hardly matters - I don't expect problems with millions of them. What does matter is the number of transactions.

Comment: @PieterWuille could you please provide more details? How should I deal with a large number of transactions? What are the consequences for bitcoind?

Comment: That's something for another question. Here you're asking about what the impact of many addresses is.

Comment: This is an opinion question and not one that can have a definitive answer. Propose to close as opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

Try it yourself. In Tools, Debug Console, try `getnewaddress`. Create as many as you want. See if your wallet performance changes. `wallet.dat` size will grow, but I can't 4MB vs 32MB has made much of a difference.

DASH wallet when it generates 1,000 addresses at a time for its PrivateSend feature, I can't notice any difference in performance.

"Effectively" manage is really seeking an opinion where the system components the node is running on will tell you what it can handle "effectively".